# Call other viewcontroller withount making new instance

Tags: swift, variables

I have a **mainTabBarController** and inside it a **mainViewController**

I have the mainTabBarController's instance in the mainViewController

**The problem** is that when I add a notification call for the hello() function in the mainTabBarC, then **it gets called twice**

mainTabBarController:

```
class MainTabBarController : UITabBarController {

    // Main Code
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("viewDidLoad")

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(hello), name: "sayHello", object: nil)
    }
    @objc func hello(){
         print("Hello")
    }
}
```

mainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UITableViewController {

    // Classes
    let mainTabBarController = MainTabBarController()

}
```

And in AppDelegate I wanna call the hello function whenever app becomes active

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "sayHello", object: nil)
}
```

Now the problem is, that I have the mainTabBarC, and inside it I have the mainViewController which contains the mainTabBarC too..

And the hello() function will be called 2x times

**How can I call a MainTabBarController function from MainViewController without creating a whole new instance?**

Comment: **Why** do you create a `MainTabBarController` inside `MainViewController`?  (Are you using a storyboard or xib files?)

Comment: storyboard. Because I have to call a function from MainTabBarController in the MainViewController

Comment: But, since this would not be the same instance of the tab controller that you load from your storyboard, either the call wouldn't do what you expect (if it affects the UI) or the function doesn't belong in a view controller (if it doesn't affect the UI).

Comment: oh.. I found out. Then if I would like to call MainTabBarC -> hello() function in the MainViewC, then I have to wrinte MainTabBarController().hello() only?

Comment: `MainTabBarController()` is what creates an extra instance.  In the case of printing "Hello" it doesn't matter but if the function does real work, you may have a problem.  (Again, printing "Hello" to the console should not be part of a view controller.)

Comment: I know, actually I'm working on a complex application, just made it a bit simplier so stackoverflowers won't get scared. I just don't understand how I can refer to the MainTabBarController's functions in an other class without creating a new instance. :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainViewController` already holds a reference to `MainTabBarController`:

[image]

You could use it in two different ways:

```
// Option 1

if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
    // do something with your tabBarController
}

// Option 2

guard let tabBarController = tabBarController else { return }

// do something with your tabBarController
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, but the correct code in MainViewController might be:

```
var mainTabBarController: MainTabBarController!
override func viewDidLoad() {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     mainTabBarController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! MainTabBarController
}
```